# TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int() float error

Tags: python

```
import csv
import requests
csv_file = "cmiday.csv"
reader = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
data = list(reader)
x=[]
y=[]
for row in data:

try:
    hum=float(row['max_rel_hum'])
    percip=float(row['precip'])
except ValueError:
    hum=None
    percip=None
if hum > 0 and hum < 100 and percip < 10 and percip > 0:
    x.append(hum)
    y.append(percip)
```

This is my code and I'm getting a

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

in line 15. Any idea how to get rid of it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting `hum` and `precip` to None?  The error is pretty clear: you can't compare None with a number.

Comment: what should i set them as?

Comment: @GeorgePopovic: What do you want the result to be?  Do you think that None is greater than 0, or less than zero?  How do you want to treat it?

Answer (score 2):

The `TypeError` is raised because you set `hum` and `percip` to `None` if a ValueError is raised. That means that you have a problem with your data while running

```
hum=float(row['max_rel_hum'])
percip=float(row['precip'])
```

One of your columns seems to contain data that can not be converted to float.

Instead of setting `hum` and `precip` to `None` you can di the following instead:

```
except ValueError:
    continue
```

This will skip the row containing invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your code results in a `ValueError`, `hum` and `percip` get set to `None`. You then try to compare `hum` and `percip` to numbers, which can't be done. To fix this, have the `except` set `hum` and `percip` to a usable value (like `0` or some other value that will produce the results you expect), skip to the next `row` with `continue`, or end the loop entirely with `break`.